How to protect the content according to the session while using the keycloak single login in next-auth
I'm using the only keycloak login as next-auth.
signIn={
        <form
          action={async () => {
            "use server";
            try {
              await signIn("keycloak");
            } catch (error) {
              if (error instanceof AuthError) {
                console.log(error);
              }
              throw error;
            }
          }}
        >
          <button>
            Sign in
          </button>
        </form>
      }

And I'm constructing middleware like this.
./middleware.ts
export { auth as middleware } from "@/auth"

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
  }

What I want is to go to the keycloak login page unconditionally if user doesn't have a session because user doesn't log in, and log out and automatically go back to the keycloak login page when the session disappears.
Here is the version what I use

"next": "14.2.3",
"next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.18",

I tried with this code, but the link went to '/login/localhost:3000/',
and I only want the only keycloak login directly,
the custom sign in page doesn't exist,
so the way I go to router won't work.
import { auth } from "@/auth";

export { auth as middleware } from "@/auth"

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
  }

  
  export default auth((req) => {
    if (!req.auth) {
      const url = req.url.replace(req.nextUrl.pathname, "/login")
      return Response.redirect(url)
    }
  })

